# two factor group_by then add row number R dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have a data frame (`df`):

```
a <- c("up","up","up","up","down","down","down","down")
b <- c("l","r","l","r","l","l","r","r")


df <- data.frame(a,b)
```

I would like to add a third column (`c`) which contains the order of entries, grouped by columns `a` and `b` that looks something like this:

```
   a   b c
1   up l 1
2   up r 1
3   up l 2
4   up r 2
5 down l 1
6 down l 2
7 down r 1
8 down r 2
```

I have tried solutions using dplyr that have not worked:

```
order <- df %>%
   group_by(a) %>%
   group_by(b) %>%
   mutate(c = row_number()) # This counts the order based on `b`, ignoring `a`

order <- df %>%
       group_by(a) %>%
       group_by(b) %>%
       mutate(c = seq_len(n())) # This counts the order based on `b`, ignoring `a`
```

I would prefer to keep using dplyr and pipes if possible, but other suggestions are welcome

Comment: what's wrong with group_by(a,b) instead of the 2 group_by statements?

Comment: Note that by default `group_by` overrides previous groups. Either use a single call, or use `add = TRUE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to combine `a` and `b` in the same `group_by` statement.

```
order <- df %>%
  group_by(a, b) %>%
  mutate(c = row_number()) 

order

# Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
# Groups: a, b [4]
# 
#       a      b     c
#   <fctr> <fctr> <int>
# 1     up      l     1
# 2     up      r     1
# 3     up      l     2
# 4     up      r     2
# 5   down      l     1
# 6   down      l     2
# 7   down      r     1
# 8   down      r     2
```